# Populate Devexpress GridView using a DataAdapter and SqlCommand in code

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, gridview, datagridview

I have a little problem with populating my DevExpress `Gridview`, I want to have a two level gridview and using `SqlCommand`. At first I created a `Dataset` and added two tables and also defined relation for them. But it does not work. Can you help me find my problem?

Here is my code

```
string owner = "SELECT [OBJECTID],[Name] ,[Family] ,[Father] ,[Dftarche] ,[Birthday] ,[education] ,[home_address] ,[farm_address] ,[ensurance] ,[phone] ,[home_number] ,[owner_id]  FROM [dbo].[OWNER]";
string property = "SELECT [number] ,[owner_ID] ,[GPSId] ,[Energy],[corp_type] ,[Pool],[irrigation]   ,[variety] ,[trees] ,[utilizat] ,[address] ,[water_hour] ,[w_source] ,[w_inche],[w_dore],[NoeMalekiat],[MotevasetBardasht],[Area] ,[OBJECTID],[Shape]  FROM [dbo].[Property] ";

string strConnString = Properties.Settings.Default.land_gisConnectionString;

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
con.Open();
 SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(owner, con);
              SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
              System.Data.DataSet dsMain = new System.Data.DataSet();
              adapter.SelectCommand = command;
              adapter.Fill(dsMain, "First Table");

              adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = property;
              adapter.Fill(dsMain, "Second Table");


              dsMain.Tables.Add(iFeatureSet.DataTable.Copy());
              adapter.Dispose();
              command.Dispose();
              DataRelation newRelation = new DataRelation("املاک شخصی", dsMain.Tables["First Table"].Columns["owner_id"], dsMain.Tables["Second Table"].Columns["owner_ID"]);
              dsMain.Relations.Add(newRelation);
              GridAttrebuteTable.DataSource = dsMain.Tables[2];
            //  gridView5.DataSource = dsMain.Tables[1];
              dataGridView1.DataSource = dsMain;
```

I searched and found this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z.aspx and it seems my code is right but it does not show anything in grids

Thank you very much for your help

**I Could figure out how to fix it.It works fine now(Above Code is edited) but now If I add a new DataTable I do not know why it does not work again**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a new `GridView` for each detail table.  You can't display both a master and detail in the same `GridView`.

[Try this example](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E3858?searchtext=master-detail)